# allow event-like communication between a thread and main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, thread-safety

I have thread on client side that waits for udp messages from server while tkinter app is running and stuff is going on. I want to modify my app according to the data the client is receiving. As far as I know modifying tkinter objects is possible only from the main thread. The problem is that the flow of the process on the main thread doesn't really allow checking queue or stuff like that so I'm looking for a solution similar to sending signal or raising exceptions or event like. any advice for how to allow the thread to communicate with the main thread would be just amazing!!

Comment: The is nothing except queues/other flags that you can share between threads when tkinter is involved. Also all tkinter events are technically part of the main thread. If you post some code, I might be able to how you how to use a queue to solve your problem. Btw I am yet to see a problem with tkinter/threading that can't be solved with queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've heard that calling `event_generate` from a thread is safe, though I don't know of a definitive source to explain whether that's true or not. There are certainly plenty of posts on the internet about this subject.

For a good description of how tkinter processes events, including a little about how tkinter works with threads, see the section titled [Event loop](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/eventloop.html) on [tkdocs.com](http://www.tkdocs.com)